# 2 wifi adapters connected to 2 separate networks. How to use one of them only?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have 2 different wireless USB adapters: **wlan0** and **wlan1**.
I have an access to 2 Wifi networks: **NETWORK_FOO** and **NETWORK_BAR**.
**wlan0** connects to **NETWORK_FOO**. **wlan1** connects to **NETWORK_BAR**.

I'd like to configure it as follows:
**wlan0** automatically makes a connection to **NETWORK_FOO** and OS always chooses this network for web connection.
**wlan1** automatically makes a connection to **NETWORK_BAR** but OS doesn't use this network.

wlan1 connection to NETWORK_BAR should be available for VM guest running on this machine.

How to do it?
(I know there's a bridge connection option, but don't know how to prevent OS from using NETWORK_BAR connection)

Answer (score 0):

Add the rules in route table. By default windows will connect to internet using network adapter based on routing information. It is automatically generated information. You can change the routing information.